# adding security to node-red dashboard

Tags: node.js, node-red

I have a small node-red/RaspberryPi project working as a garage door controller with a node-red dashboard UI.

I'd like to add authentication and expose the UI to the internet so I can check status remotely.

Working from https://nodered.org/docs/security I tried

```
node-red-admin hash-pw
```

resulting in 'command not found'. Trying the alternative:

```
node -e "console.log(require('bcryptjs').hashSync(process.argv[1], 8));" secret-password
```

results in an error in module.js:471 'cannot find module bcryptjs'.

The instructions do say to run this 'from within the Node-RED install directory'. Which is... where? I ran this command from ~/.node-red. In desperation I tried 'sudo apt-get install bcryptjs' but that did not work.

So - not a Linux expert, and a complete newbie at javascript; how can I restrict the use of my node red UI to authorized users?

Also - might there be a user forum (other than stack exchange)?

Comment: Which directory where you in when you ran the command? You need to be in the node-red install directory so it can find the bundled pre-reqs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to be in the Node-RED install directory (probably /usr/lib/node_modules/node-red) for that command to work.

It's better to use the `node-red-admin hash-pw` command if possible as that will make sure all the paths are correct.

Node-RED has a [Google Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/node-red) and a [Slack Team](https://nodered.org/slack) for discussing things.

Comment: bash doesn't understand 'node-red-admin'. Does that depend on what directory I run it from?

Comment: no it depends on how you installed node-red, npm or apt-get or some other way?

Comment: running 'node -e...' from that folder worked perfectly - thanks.